# On double click on empty space, how to prevent it's not being selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my table, when i double click on the empty space, it's selected ( highlighted in blue ),  how can i avoid this. but still i need to select the text on the rows.

i tried like this, but no use:

```
table{
    width:100%;
}

td{
    border:1px solid gray;
    -webkit-user-select  : text; //still empty space selected.
}
```

any one give some suggestion please? ( in demo click on empty space on td )

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PEdq5/)

Comment: It is the default behavior of browser .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one method...

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/PEdq5/2/**

Add some markup (inline elements surrounding the text/cell contents)

### Updated HTML

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="denali-tooltip tooltip-on-truncate project-name">Mahindra</span>
            </td>
            <td><span>1</span>
            </td>
            <td><span>19</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then add some CSS using the `::selection` pseudo-element rule that affects the default selection behaviour.

### Additional CSS

```
td::selection {
    background-color: transparent;
}
td > span::selection {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}
```

Additional information on `::selection`. Note that this is a non-standard feature.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection
http://caniuse.com/#search=%3A%3Aselection

Comment: bt not working in firfox and also in chrome if we are clicking thrice it is selected

Comment: @prash use `::-moz-selection` in FF. This is a non-standard feature. This does not disable the default text selection behaviour but instead "shrinks" the visual effect to only occur when clicking on the span itself. I would argue that changing the **default, expected behaviour** is not a sensible thing to do.

Comment: Yes, but the OP was asking about DOUBLE-clicking. If you also want to prevent the text from being selected when triple-clicked, you have to use JS I think.

Comment: @FlorianGl "In my table, when i double click on the empty space, it's selected". My proposed solution stops the doubl-eclick on *empty* space. The triple-click is increasing the selection to child elements. This is not behaviour that can easily be remedied. I will wait for feedback from the OP before I make any changes to my proposed answer.

Comment: @gvee This should have been an answer to the comment from prash.

Comment: @FlorianGl apologies, misdirected comment! :)

Comment: @gvee according to you, always i should keep some internal element to prevent the selection! (like "span" ).

Comment: @3gwebtrain If I have interpreted the question correctly, yes. If this solution does not meet your requirements then I'm afraid that your requirements are not clear enough to me and I must ask you to elaborate (illustration may be useful).

Comment: my question is very simple, wherever the suer double clicks on the page, the empty space should be 'trasnparent' - but the image, text are selectable by default. fox example i am looking like this 'emptyspace'::selection { background-color: transparent; }

Comment: means? In my page, user double clicks on empty spaces ( there is no.of divs has min-heights ) being selected and became blue patch. my QA team ask to fix this..

Comment: @3gwebtrain then I suspect the entire answer is: `::selection {background-color: transparent;}`

Comment: but text nodes will not be selected right. is there any text node selector, so textNode::selection{background:blue} - to use?

Comment: @3gwebtrain text can appear within almost all HTML elements.

Answer (score 1):

Add `display:block;` to the span element.
Double click wont select the text anymore, just triple-click will.

Comment: Nothing much to show, I just added display:block; to span element. I tried it on IE11, maybe other browser show different behaviors.

Comment: I am looking especially chrome and safari.

Answer (score 1):

### Alternative JS Method

```
document.onselectstart = function() {return false;}
document.onmousedown = function() {return false;}
```

This will disable the selection of anything on the page by the mouse. It is not bulletproof in any way can easily cause you problems with the interoperability of other click functions you might be using in JS among many, many other drawbacks.

I do not condone this kind of code, but it should adequately answer the question.